# update nvarchar not null field length

Tags: sql-server, null, alter-table

I can update the column's length if it in null when created

```
MYCOLUMN1 nvarchar(12) NULL
```

My query:

```
Alter table MYTABLE ALTER Column MYCOLUMN1 nvarchar(13) NULL
```

but how can I change the length if column is not null?

```
MYCOLUMN2 nvarchar(12) NOT NULL

Alter table MYTABLE ALTER Column MYCOLUMN2 nvarchar(13) NOT NULL
```

when I try to do that SQL Server says

> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object "MYCOLUMN2" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

I have permission because i am admin and table's column does exist.

Guys thanks for your response...
Here is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE](
    [MyKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mycolumn1] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [mycolumn2] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_MYTABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MyKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Post your table as well to your question

Comment: are you sure there is a column "mycolumn2" in your table?

Comment: Looks like the column name would be mis-spelled or not exist in the table.

Comment: Just use `ALTER TABLE dbo.MYTABLE ALTER COLUMN MYCOLUMN2 NVARCHAR(13) NOT NULL` - if it was `NOT NULL` before, just use `NOT NULL` again in your `ALTER TABLE` command ....

Answer (score 1):

Column names are case sensitive. Please try

```
Alter table MYTABLE ALTER Column [mycolumn2] nvarchar(13) NOT NULL
```

I've tried and it works fine on sqlserver2012.